# How to plot this data in correct date order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this (in date order):

```
freq date
3    Jan-18
2    Feb-18
42   Mar-18
2    Apr-18
4    May-18
```

However, when I plot this with the following code, it doesn't order by the order saved in the data frame. Instead it plots them in alphabetical order (see x-axis). How can this be fixed so that the plot is done in the order saved in the data frame?

Note that the date column is of type character which is likely why, but changing this to date format is tricky since there is no day, and when you do so it changes e.g. Jun-18 to 01-1918-06, which doesn't look nice on a graph. So, I'm trying to do this without changing it to date format if possible.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = freq)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Also worth checking how is R/ ggplot is seeing it. Use `class(df$date)` to make sure it sees the column as date. Use lubridate package to convert to the correct class if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way and if data is showed as in example could be:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>%
  mutate(date=factor(date,levels = unique(date),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=freq))+
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

Or formatting the date variable:

```
#Code2
df %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(paste0(date,'-01'),'%b-%y-%d')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=freq))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b-%y')+
  ggtitle('My title')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
structure(list(freq = c(3L, 2L, 42L, 2L, 4L), date = c("Jan-18", 
"Feb-18", "Mar-18", "Apr-18", "May-18")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you! For your first solution, if I try to use `geom_line()` instead of `geom_point()`, the data does not appear on the graph. Do you know why/how to fix?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 Hi dear, I tested and worked with geom_line, try this please `geom_line(aes(group=1))`

Comment: Perfect, thank you - this worked. What does group = 1 refer to for interest?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 That option creates a fit so that there is only one line, it also depends on what data you are plotting!

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert the data to a zoo series with yearmon index (which can represent a year and month without a day) in which case it is straight-forward using `autoplot.zoo` .  Omit the geom argument if you want a line plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df, index = "date", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y")
autoplot(z, geom = "point") + scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** This also works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.yearmon(date, format = "%b-%y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, freq)) + geom_point() + scale_x_yearmon()
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
freq date
3    Jan-18
2    Feb-18
42   Mar-18
2    Apr-18
4    May-18"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I haven't used zoo before - do you know whether it's possible to edit this in ggplot? Like changing the titles etc?

Comment: Append  `+ ggtitle("my series")` onto the end of the `autoplot` or `ggplot` line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on the zoo package, you could simply pick a year (e.g. 2021) and the conversion of the date column in your example works fine. You can then specify how the date is displayed in ggplot2's `scale_x_date()`. [Here is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMxJ7.png)

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
freq date
3    Jan-18
2    Feb-18
42   Mar-18
2    Apr-18
4    May-18")

df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, "-2021"), format = "%B-%d-%Y")


ggplot(df, aes(date, y = freq)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Frequency") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```